# Terminated & Not In Group

Tags: powershell, active-directory, account, active-directory-group, powershell-1.0

I'm trying to generate a report for all disabled accounts that don't have the group "Terminated Employees" but it isn't seeming to generate the report. Below is the code that I have at the moment.

**TLDR:** The text file contains a list of all the disabled accounts and I am trying to cross reference that list with the list of people in Terminated Employees and then return to a CSV file the accounts that are in that list and **not** in the group "Terminated Employees".

Also note that we need to bypass the limit of `Get-ADGroupMember` as there are over 5000 members in this group.

```
$ADGroupName = "Terminated Employees"
$users = Get-Content C:\Shortcuts\users.txt
$InputPath= "C:\Scripts\T_Accounts.csv"

$a = @(Get-ADGroup $ADGroupName | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Member)

foreach ($user in $users) {
    if ($a -contains $user) {
    "Member found"
    } else {
        $SplitStep1 = ($Member -split ",",2)[0]
        $SplitStep2 = ($SplitStep1 -split "=",2)[1]
        $SplitStep2 = $SplitStep2 | Out-File -Append $InputPath
    }
}

foreach ($value in (Get-Content $InputPath)) {
    $b = Get-ADUser -Identity $value -Properties DisplayName, sAMAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled
}
```

Comment: Not near test domain to check this over, but something like this should do what you want... `Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled -UsersOnly | Get-Aduser -Properties memberof | Where-Object {!($_.memberof -like "Terminated Employees")}` then use `Select-Object` & `Export-Csv` to export the required properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using `Import-Csv` and `Export-Csv` cmdlets handling input and output files. And if we are searching disabled user accounts, which are members of specific group, there should be no need for the input file at all.
How about this oneliner:

```
Get-ADGroup "Terminated Employees" -Properties Members |
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members |
Get-ADUser -Properties Enabled, Displayname, LastLogonDate |
Where-Object {$_.Enabled -eq $false} |
Select-Object DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled |
Export-Csv outfile.txt
```

Edit: Should have internalized the original question before rushing to answer. I think the clearest way is to create two sets of users and compare them, exporting results to CSV file.

```
$disabledusers = Get-Aduser -filter "Enabled -eq '$false'" -properties
DisplayName, SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled | select DisplayName,
SamAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled

$groupmembers = Get-ADGroup "Terminated Employees" -Properties Members| 
Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members | Get-ADUser -Properties DisplayName,
sAMAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled | select DisplayName, SamAccountName,
LastLogonDate, Enabled

Compare-Object $groupmembers $disabledusers -Property enabled -PassThru |
?{$_.sideindicator -eq "=>"} | select DisplayName, SamAccountName,
LastLogonDate, Enabled | export-csv outfile.txt
```

Comment: How will this catch the disabled users that are NOT a member of the group "Terminated Employees"?

Comment: That second one works amazingly! Thanks! :) Just needed to at the file path of the export and I decided to change it to a csv file for the benefit of everyone's eyes. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't requesting the `Members` property from ActiveDirectory in your `Get-ADGroup` command (also need to add the `s` to `Members` in your `Select-Object` ;) ).

```
$ADGroupName = "Terminated Employees"
$users = Get-Content C:\Shortcuts\users.txt
$InputPath= "C:\Scripts\T_Accounts.csv"

# Here we need to add the -Properties parameter to ask ActiveDirectory for the group Members
$a = @(Get-ADGroup -Identity $ADGroupName -Properties Members | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Members)


ForEach ($user in $users)
{
if ($a -contains $user)
{
"Member found"
}
else 
{
 $SplitStep1 = ($Member -split ",",2)[0]
 $SplitStep2 = ($SplitStep1 -split "=",2)[1]
 $SplitStep2 = $SplitStep2 | out-file -Append $InputPath
}
}


ForEach ($value in (Get-Content $InputPath))
{
 $b = Get-ADUser -identity $value -Properties DisplayName, sAMAccountName, LastLogonDate, Enabled
}
```

Comment: RIP, didn't seem to work... The CSV only contains "ÿþ" in Cell 1